# How to construct a figure using tikz package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need to make a figure using tikz package which would look similar to the example below (shapes of the objects in this example are not required - could be just rectangle as well):

[image]

Comment: Starting point: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/

Comment: This can be a good start: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191001/how-to-draw-a-hierarchical-diagram-in-tikz

Comment: Some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly more succinct translation of your solution. The nodes are first created in a `matrix of nodes`. These are then joined using a few loops. Because a `matrix of nodes` names each node automatically, it isn't necessary to specify the names explicitly. By naming the matrix `(M)`, the nodes are named according to the schema `(M-<row>-<column>)`. I tried connecting them with `graphs` syntax, but graph syntax and matrices are not, it seems, a marriage made in heaven :(.

This also demonstrates a couple of different ways of customising all nodes in the matrix, all nodes in a row or individual nodes on-the-fly, and illustrates some other possible shapes suggested by the target image in the question.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix,arrows.meta,shapes.misc,shapes.symbols,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth, shape aspect=.25]
  \matrix (M) [matrix of nodes, every node/.style={font=\itshape, anchor=center, text centered, draw, text width=6.1em, minimum height=3em}, column sep=10mm, row sep=10mm, row 5/.append style={rounded rectangle}, row 4/.append style={rounded corners}, row 7/.append style={rounded corners}, row 3/.append style={shape border rotate=90, cylinder}]
  {
    && |[cylinder, shape border rotate=90]| {Imbalanced\\Data} && \\
    && |[rounded corners]| {Data\\Balancing} && \\
    {Balanced\\Data\textsubscript{1}} & {Balanced\\Data\textsubscript{2}} & |[draw=none]|$\cdots$ & {Balanced\\Data\textsubscript{K-1}} & {Balanced\\Data\textsubscript{K}} \\
    Modeling & Modeling & |[draw=none]|$\cdots$  &  Modeling & Modeling \\
    {Classifier\textsubscript{1}} & {Classifier\textsubscript{2}} & |[draw=none]|$\cdots$ & {Classifier\textsubscript{K-1}} & {Classifier\textsubscript{K}} \\
    & & |[rounded rectangle]| {Ensemble\\Classifying} & & \\
    & New Data & Classifying & & \\
    & & |[tape, tape bend top=none]| {Classification\\Results} & & \\
  };
  \coordinate [below=5mm of M-2-3] (p);
  \coordinate [above=5mm of M-6-3] (q);
  \foreach \i/\j in {M-1-3/M-2-3,M-6-3/M-7-3,M-7-3/M-8-3,M-7-2/M-7-3} \draw [->, thick] (\i) -- (\j);
  \foreach \i/\j in {3/4,4/5} \foreach \k in {1,2,4,5} \draw [->, thick] (M-\i-\k) -- (M-\j-\k);
  \draw [thick] (M-2-3) -- (p) \foreach \i in {1,2,4,5} {(M-5-\i) |- (q) (p) -- (p -| M-3-\i)};
  \draw [->, thick] \foreach \i in {1,2,4,5} {(p -| M-3-\i) edge  (M-3-\i)} (q) -- (M-6-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: concise code with fancy shapes]

Comment: I have a problem with textsubscript, when applied to a number like: \textsubscript{2} it works, but with a letter like here: \textsubscript{K-1} the letter "K" is not subscripted, so the result looks like: DataK_{-1}

Comment: @qerigan As you can see, it works for me. You'd need to give a minimal example which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just copy-pased your solution and the \textsubscript just ignores the "K" letter in brackets. Perhaps some package is missing? Link to image example http://imgur.com/KRocWD5

Comment: I can't explain that. It seems very strange indeed. I suggest looking at the console output and in your logs for clues. Right now, I can't imagine how precisely this code could produce that output, so I need more information!

Answer (score 2):

If someone need something similar in future here is what I built.

```
\tikzstyle{box}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, text centered, anchor=north, text width=6.1em, minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{myarrow}=[->, thick, shorten >=1pt]
\tikzstyle{line}=[-, thick]

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Split schema}
    \label{fig:split}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
        \node (ImbalancedData) [box] {$Imbalanced$\\$Data$};
        \node (DataBalancing) [box, below=0.5cm of ImbalancedData] {$Data$\\$Balancing$};
        \node (AuxNode01) [below=1.4cm of DataBalancing] {$\cdots$};
            \node (BalancedData2) [box, left=of AuxNode01] {$Balanced$\\$Data_{2}$};
            \node (BalancedData1) [box, left=of BalancedData2] {$Balanced$\\$Data_{1}$};
            \node (BalancedDataK-1) [box, right=of AuxNode01] {$Balanced$\\$Data_{K-1}$};
            \node (BalancedDataK) [box, right=of BalancedDataK-1] {$Balanced$\\$Data_{K}$};
        \node (AuxNode02) [below=1.4cm of AuxNode01] {$\cdots$};
            \node (Modeling2) [box, left=of AuxNode02] {$Modeling$};
            \node (Modeling1) [box, left=of Modeling2] {$Modeling$};
            \node (Modeling3) [box, right=of AuxNode02] {$Modeling$};
            \node (Modeling4) [box, right=of Modeling3] {$Modeling$};
        \node (AuxNode03) [below=1.4cm of AuxNode02] {$\cdots$};
            \node (Classifier2) [box, left=of AuxNode03] {$Classifier_{2}$};
            \node (Classifier1) [box, left=of Classifier2] {$Classifier_{1}$};
            \node (ClassifierK-1) [box, right=of AuxNode03] {$Classifier_{K-1}$};
            \node (ClassifierK) [box, right=of ClassifierK-1] {$Classifier_{K}$};
        \node (EnsembleClassifying) [box, below=1.4cm of AuxNode03] {$Ensemble$\\$Classifying$};
        \node (Classifying) [box, below=0.5 of EnsembleClassifying] {$Classifying$};
        \node (NewData) [box, left=1.5 of Classifying] {$New Data$};
        \node (ClassificationResults) [box, below=0.5 of Classifying] {$Classification$\\$Results$};

        \draw[myarrow] (ImbalancedData.south) -- (DataBalancing.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (DataBalancing.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (BalancedData1.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (DataBalancing.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (BalancedData2.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (DataBalancing.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (BalancedDataK-1.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (DataBalancing.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (BalancedDataK.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (BalancedData1.south) -- (Modeling1.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (BalancedData2.south) -- (Modeling2.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (BalancedDataK-1.south) -- (Modeling3.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (BalancedDataK.south) -- (Modeling4.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (Modeling1.south) -- (Classifier1.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (Modeling2.south) -- (Classifier2.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (Modeling3.south) -- (ClassifierK-1.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (Modeling4.south) -- (ClassifierK.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (Classifier1.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (EnsembleClassifying.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (Classifier2.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (EnsembleClassifying.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (ClassifierK-1.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (EnsembleClassifying.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (ClassifierK.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (EnsembleClassifying.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (EnsembleClassifying.south) -- (Classifying.north);
        \draw[myarrow] (NewData.east) -- (Classifying.west);
        \draw[myarrow] (Classifying.south) -- (ClassificationResults.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not necessary to put the contents of the nodes inside `$`, you can remove them for normal text or if you want italic text you would be better off enclosing it with `\textit{foo}` as this will properly handle the spacings between letters.

Comment: Nice. `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, though. `tikzset{}` is fortunately less typing and current ;).

Comment: Since you've added this for future reference, you should also update the question title to reflect its content.