# Using native Tikz tree or forest?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest, trees

I just have a very philosophical(?) question. At this time i am well in drawing pictures with tikz. Now i have to make some tree-like diagramms and ask myself which "package" i should use for this? In the Tikz manual there is already some sort of mechanism for drawing trees. More, I often heard of the package forest but which have a complete different syntax.
Does it make sense to put effort in getting to know "forest" or is it the same as using the tikz mechanism?
I dont want to change all of my work later on so I try my best to figure out which option should be used.

So in simple words:
Forest >>>> Tikz?
or ist it just the personal preference that counts and both are great?

EDIT: I want to achieve a "tree" 
[like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCDQK.jpg)

Is therefore tikz, qtree or forest the best option?

Comment: I am afraid that this question will be closed since it is opinion-based. Note however that `forest` is based on Ti*k*Z, so it is indeed *not* *very* different.

Comment: @marmot I agree that this is opinion based, but if SRel modifies the question to ask for what are the differences, it could be made into a non-opinion based question. And IMO they are quite different. The base TikZ tree drawing syntax is terrible, and it does no automatic packing or separating of nodes. The  `forest` input syntax is simple and it can do many things programmatically, which in the base methods are I'm sure possible, but by no means trivial.

Comment: @AlanMunn I agree, and I am not too good at closing questions either. (For all the reasons you mention you did *not* use forest [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438633/121799), right? Just kidding. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Well I'm very orthodox: if it ain't a tree, don't use `forest`. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn It depends on the kind of tree, too. Maybe the `istgame` thing is easier for game-theory trees, though obviously less flexible. And the tree layout algorithms of Ti*k*Z might be nice, if your trees require that level of automation. Otherwise, if it is a tree in the graph-theory sense, Forest; otherwise Ti*k*Z.

Comment: @OP Please edit your question into something people can answer here. (Unless you're happy to have it closed.) Please be a bit more specific about the kind of tree you need to draw, too, as some packages are only for special kinds of trees, while others are more general.

Comment: Okay I am fine with these comments. I see no function to mark this "question" as closed. How can I do that? But still that I can see this later on with having a look at the comments :) the tree should be some general tree, visualizing some sort of experimental methods like block matching. It's a tree which is even on each side, each level has elements.

Comment: I added an "answer" specifying the tree I want to achieve. Maybe the merge at the end could be problematic? However later I may want to create a much huge tree and therefore want to meant one package either forest or tikz or may qtree

Comment: The merge at the end requires some extra work but certainly can be done with forest or without.

Comment: That is not a tree in the relevant sense (and should be in your question - not in the answer space). Hence no tree-drawing package can draw it straightforwardly, although you can use a tree-drawing package to do the bit which is a tree. A tree has a single root and all its descendants have exactly one parent. That's the kind of tree `forest`, `qtree`, `tikz-qtree` etc. draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why to restrict to `TikZ-tree` or `forest`? A simple `matrix` also solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={align=center, text width=2.4cm},
    column sep=5mm, row sep=2mm] (A) {
&&&{Group 1\\ 300 Subjects}&{Treatment 1\\ Drug X 325 mg}& \\
&{600\\ Men}&{Random\\ Assignment} & & & Compare Drop in Temperature\\
&&&{Group 2\\ 300 Subjects}&{Treatment 2\\ Placebo}& \\
{1200\\ Subjects} & & & & &\\
&&&{Group 1\\ 300 Subjects}&{Treatment 1\\ Drug X 325 mg}& \\
&{600\\ Women}&{Random\\ Assignment} & & & Compare Drop in Temperature\\
&&&{Group 2\\ 300 Subjects}&{Treatment 2\\ Placebo}& \\
};

\draw[->] (A-4-1)--(A-2-2);
\draw[->] (A-2-2)--(A-2-3);
\draw[->] (A-2-3)--(A-1-4);
\draw[->] (A-1-4)--(A-1-5);
\draw[->] (A-1-5)--(A-2-6);

\draw[->] (A-2-3)--(A-3-4);
\draw[->] (A-3-4)--(A-3-5);
\draw[->] (A-3-5)--(A-2-6);

\draw[->] (A-4-1)--(A-6-2);
\draw[->] (A-6-2)--(A-6-3);
\draw[->] (A-6-3)--(A-5-4);
\draw[->] (A-5-4)--(A-5-5);
\draw[->] (A-5-5)--(A-6-6);

\draw[->] (A-6-3)--(A-7-4);
\draw[->] (A-7-4)--(A-7-5);
\draw[->] (A-7-5)--(A-6-6);

\node[draw, below right=of A.south west, anchor=north west, inner xsep=3mm] (B) {Assignment to block is not random};

\draw[<-] (A-4-1)--(A-4-1|-B.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

Just to show that `forest` is probably better for schemes more similar to  trees. I'm not a `forest` expert, so it's not perfect: lower `Placebo` nodes are not equally aligned. I hope someone could help.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[1200\\ Subjects, for tree={align=center, grow'=east}
    [600\\ Men
        [{Random\\ Assignment}
            [{Group 1\\ 300 Subjects}
                [{Treatment 1\\ Drug X 325 mg}
                    [,phantom]
                    [,phantom]
                    [Compare Drop\\ in Temperature, name=aux11]
                ]
            ]
            [{Group 2\\ 300 Subjects}
                [{Treatment 2\\ Placebo}, name=aux12
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [{600\\ Women}
        [{Random\\ Assignment}
            [{Group 1\\ 300 Subjects}
                [{Treatment 1\\ Drug X 325 mg}
                    [,phantom]
                    [,phantom]
                    [Compare Drop\\ in Temperature, name=aux21]
                ]
            ]
            [{Group 2\\ 300 Subjects}
                [{Treatment 2\\ Placebo}, name=aux22
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\draw (aux11)--(aux12) (aux21)--(aux22);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did nearly everything else before with a matrix to arrange nodes and just wanted to learn something new. But I see you are right, matrix seems the easiest solution for this

Comment: @SRel It's the easiest solution in this particular case because its even simmetry, but a matrix won't solve all possibilites. But this case (which is not a `tree`) you could use forest (or tikz-tree) to build the `tree` part add two right nodes with tikz commands. Forest is worth to learn.