# How to get limited multidominance in a forest tree

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, linguistics

I would like to have `forest` trees that allow a very limited kind of multidominance, as shown in the picture below:

[image: multidominant tree]

The basic idea is that the terminal node *a* is centred between and dominated by both X nodes.

This was produced in the following hacky way: I made a ternary branching tree with a phantom middle edge so that the terminal was the terminal node of the middle branch and then manually drew multidominant the branches.  This works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a less hacky way to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{multi/.style={before typesetting nodes={
     prepend={[X,name=X1,tier=x]},
     append={[X,name=X2,tier=x]}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [A,s sep=0pt,multi
        [X,phantom, tier=x [a,tier=s,name=X ]]
    ]
\draw (X1.south) -- (X.north);
\draw (X2.south) -- (X.north);
\end{forest} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Isn't that what [@cfr's "not a tree"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438619/121799) does?

Comment: @marmot Yes perhaps. This is one of those cases where 'less hacky' ≠ 'easy to understand'.

Comment: @marmot In that code I can't see the tree in the forest. :)

Comment: I do advise against using Forest.

Comment: @cfr If you're around could talk about this in the chat?

Comment: @cfr https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99513/multidominance-room

Comment: You don't like my answer after all? :(

Comment: @cfr I actually thought the bounty got applied automatically to the accepted answer if there was only one. But it's officially awarded now. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=9pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{
  declare toks={multi name}{},
  multi dom/.style={
    if={>On={level}{0}}{}{%
      delay/.process={OOw2}{name}{multi name}{
        insert before={[##2,tier=##1]},
        insert after={[##2,tier=##1]},
        !u.s sep'=0pt,
      },
      before typesetting nodes={
        replace by/.process={OOw2}{name}{multi name}{[##2, phantom, before drawing tree={content=, no edge, phantom=0, typeset node}, tier=##1, delay={append=##1}]}
      },
      edge path'={(!up.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor) -- (!un.parent anchor)},
    },
  },
  multi/.style={
    multi name=#1,
    multi dom,
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [A
    [a,multi=X ]
  ]
\end{forest} 
\begin{forest}
  [A
    [a,multi=X ]
    [b [c,multi=C] ]
    [f [g,multi=H] ]
  ]
\end{forest} 
\begin{forest}
  for tree={multi name=J}
  [A
    [a,multi dom ]
    [b [c,multi=C] ]
    [f [g,multi dom] ]
  ]
\end{forest} 
\begin{forest}
  [C [A
      [a, multi=C  ]
  ]
    [B [c,multi=V ]]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: too many oppressed children being dominated by parents]