# Vertex labeling emptyset

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees

I want to draw a tree which contains nodes that are from 2 or more paarents is there any way to set this up with tikz and trees

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% input encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% new german spelling
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% choose font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% KOMA-Script options
\KOMAoptions{%
  parskip=full,%
  fontsize=12pt,%
  DIV=calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
  level/.style={
    sibling distance=20mm/#1
  },
  level distance=10mm,
}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Empty]
\Vertex{$\emptyset$}
\Vertex[x=2,y=0]{Q}
\Vertex[x=1,y=-2]{X}
\Vertex[x=-1,y=-2]{Z}
\Vertex[x=3,y=-2]{R}
\Vertex[x=0,y=-3]{A}
\Vertex[x=2,y=-3]{B}
\Vertex[x=-1,y=-4]{C}
\Vertex[x=1,y=-4]{D}
\Vertex[x=3,y=-4]{E}
\Edges(Z,X,Q,R) 
\Edges(A,X,B)
\Edges(C,A,D,B,E)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such things are called multi dominant trees, and the answer is yes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511136.

Comment: Since these aren't really trees, there are no out of the box methods. See [Multi-rooted Tree-like Structures and Nodes with Multiple Parents in LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/114109) [How to get limited multidominance in a forest tree](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/451026).

Comment: But with forests i can't connect 2 nodes of different trees

Comment: You got two links that show you how to start. If you want to get an explicit answer, please consider providing us with an explicit code that illustrates what you have tried, and where you got stuck.

Comment: Actually using \vertex could you tell me how i could name a node with \emptyset? That's my only issue for that one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to give the vertex a displayed name that differs from its identifier, use the `L` key. See section 5 of the `tkz-graph` manual. (No, I do not speak French, but one can guess this from the examples.)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% input encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% new german spelling
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% choose font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% KOMA-Script options
\KOMAoptions{%
  parskip=full,%
  fontsize=12pt,%
  DIV=calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
  level/.style={
    sibling distance=20mm/#1
  },
  level distance=10mm,
}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Empty]
\Vertex[L=$\emptyset$]{Y}
\Vertex[x=2,y=0]{Q}
\Vertex[x=1,y=-2]{X}
\Vertex[x=-1,y=-2]{Z}
\Vertex[x=3,y=-2]{R}
\Vertex[x=0,y=-3]{A}
\Vertex[x=2,y=-3]{B}
\Vertex[x=-1,y=-4]{C}
\Vertex[x=1,y=-4]{D}
\Vertex[x=3,y=-4]{E}
\Edges(Z,Y,X,Q,R) 
\Edges(A,X,B)
\Edges(C,A,D,B,E)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]