# How can I draw a tree diagram where leafs are connected to converging branches?

Tags: forest

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
% Styling
for tree={
align=center,
parent anchor=south,
child anchor=north,
edge={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
l sep+=10pt,
edge path={
\noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
},
if level=0{
inner xsep=-15pt,
tikz={\draw [thick] (.south east) -- (.south west);}
}{}
}
%
[Alphabet
[a
[b]
[c] ]
[b
[d]
[e] ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

How would I be able to connect all the branches in the manner shown below in the sketch

[image]
[image]

Comment: it would be helpful to place a handrawn sketch of the requirement

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. By joining the leaves, your diagram is no longer a tree. As discussed here: [Lost in the Forest — Merging after Branching?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438619/) there are other ways of drawing such structures. As that answer shows, a solution using `Forest` is possible, but it does involve learning syntax specific to `Forest`. It might be better to adopt the `matrix of nodes` approach and learn basic `TikZ` syntax that can then be extended to many other applications.

Comment: Please give a clearer specification of what you want — a simple sketch would be ideal, as @js_bibra suggests. Currently the question is essentially unanswerable: I can imagine half a dozen very different looking arrangements that could fit your description.

Comment: Sketch Provided Above.

Answer (score 4):

## Update 2: Arrows between nodes with nodewalk specification

All additional arrows *(not built natively by forest)* that connect two nodes are placed in the tree with the short **node walk** syntax.  This **without naming** the nodes as before *(a real style exercise)*.
In order to allow the visualization of these arrows, I colored them in **red**.

I quote the manual:

> A nodewalk is a concise way of expressing node relations. It is simply
> a string of steps, which are represented by single characters, where:
> **u** stands for the parent node (up); **p** for the previous sibling; **n** for the next sibling; **s** for *the* sibling (useful only in binary trees); **1**, **2**, . . . **9** for first, second, . . .
> ninth child; l, for the last child, etc. For the complete
> specification, see section **3.8.7**.

[image: with nodewalk]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
% Styling
for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    edge={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
    l sep+=10pt,
    edge path={\noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
},
if level=0{inner xsep=-15pt,tikz={\draw [thick] (.south east) -- (.south west);}
}{}
}
%
[Alphabet
    [a
        [b]
        [c,s sep=10,
        [f,s sep=30,
            [,phantom]
            [z,edge={white}]
                {\draw[thick,red,-{Stealth[]}] (!rllN.south east) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (!c); %<-- arrow from g to z
                \draw[thick,red] (!uss.south west) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (!c) ;%<-- arrow from f to z
           }
        ]{\draw[thick,red,shorten >=3pt] (!us.south) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (!c) ;}%<-- arrow from b to f
        [,phantom]          
        ] 
    ]
    [b
        [d]
        [e,s sep=9
            [g]{\draw[thick,red,shorten >=3pt] (!us.south) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (!c) ;}%<-- arrow from d to g
            [,phantom]         
        ] 
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

## In response to an update

I've done a lot of tinkering to achieve this result and so I'm not sure I coded elegantly. If a forest expert comes by, I'm listening to what improvements can be made.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
% Styling
for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    edge={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
    l sep+=10pt,
    edge path={\noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
},
if level=0{inner xsep=-15pt,tikz={\draw [thick] (.south east) -- (.south west);}
}{}
}
%
[Alphabet
    [a
        [b,name=b]
        [c,s sep=10,
        [f,name=f,s sep=30,
            [,phantom]
            [z,name=z,edge={white}]
        ]
        [,phantom]          
        ] 
    ]
    [b
        [d,name=d]
        [e,s sep=9
            [g,name=g]
            [,phantom]         
        ] 
    ]
]
\draw[thick,shorten >=2pt] (b.south) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (f.north);
\draw[thick,shorten >=2pt] (d.south) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (g.north);
\draw[thick,shorten >=2pt] (g.south east) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (z.north);
\draw[thick,-{Stealth[]}] (f.south west) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (z.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

## Old answer

There may be a more elegant solution, but here is my proposal.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
%\usepackage{mdframed}
%\usepackage{boxedminipage}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
% Styling
for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    edge={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
    l sep+=10pt,
    edge path={\noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
},
if level=0{inner xsep=-15pt,tikz={\draw [thick] (.south east) -- (.south west);}
}{}
}
%
[Alphabet
    [a
        [b,name=b]
        [c,name=c
            [,phantom]
            [z,name=z]
        ] 
    ]
    [b
        [d,name=d]
        [e,name=e] 
    ]
]
\draw[thick,shorten >=2pt] (b.south) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (z.north);
\draw[thick,shorten >=2pt] (d.south) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (z.north);
\draw[thick,shorten >=2pt] (e.south) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (z.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Andre. What would be the adjusted MWE if I were to request the above-edited sketch?

Comment: Yours is not too bad, just remove the packages that are not used, everything is very well explained here. [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: Cheers, and how would I be able to produce the sketch I just added above? Apologies as I am new to learning the forest package.

Comment: I don't know this package very well myself *(I never use it personally)*. I spent a lot of time this morning trying to understand the syntax, which is not trivial *(whatever the specialists say)*. I'm thinking about your update. Let's hope that a forest specialist answers before me, because it will take me some time. I want you to know that I voted for your question because I always vote for the questions that have interested me so much that I think about them and write an answer.