# Is 'tikz' the best solution for this diagram in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, diagrams, geogebra

[image]

I know the tikz package is recommended.
But I have no idea how to start it.

If there is any example similar to that of mine, I might refer to the example.

I made it using "draw.io" and "geogebra".
I drew the diagram (rectangles, rhombuses and arrays) by using "draw.io"
and typed the equations like ax+by+c=0 by using "geogebra".
So it's just a png file and I just used \includegraphics.

But I don't like the font of something like 'coincide', it doesn't match the font of the original document.
(In fact, the word 'coincide' should be '평행', which is korean, yet I don't like the font)

Between "tikz" and "draw.io+geogebra", which is less complicated and looks good in making such diagrams?

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: this very opinion based question ... (and as such it will probably closed)- shortly: it depends which of possible packages you master.

Comment: OP says he has "no idea how to start it". Recently I read Prof. Paulinho van Duck's article in TUGBoat. Is that available online? I think it's an excellent start...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, the duckboats are available, for example   https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-3/tb120duck.pdf

Comment: @samcarter No, Phelype is referring to the second one.

Comment: @shyzealot maybe as starting point: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Prof. van Duck is very happy you appreciate his article. By now it is available only to TUG members. It'll be available to everyone in a year's time.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Good to know! However reading the first duckboat won't harm :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX But I think the link to the second DuckBoat is broken... I have this year's institutional membership but when I click the link to the article I get a **Not Found**, while the others appear fine :/

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'll tell Barbara :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks :) Just adding to the list, Hans Hagen's `Executing TeX in Lua: Coroutines` doesn't work for me too. The others are fine.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for your comments. So I have to choose a package, if there is a good one.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. So, it's for beginners like me. Thank you.

Comment: After all, here is "tex.stackexchange.com". So I think the main question should be "how can I make such diagram using tikz in LaTeX?". Thanks for good references and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way I can claim any option is the best, but I would like to argue that it is at least very advantageous to have a code that produces vector graphics pdf files. One possibility is to use forest and get some fair amount of inspiration from some of @cfr's answers like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438628/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow'=east,calign = first,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries,
    child anchor=west,
    l sep=10mm,
    s sep=5mm,
    anchor=east,
    align=center,draw,
    child anchor=parent,
    parent anchor=children,
    where level={1}{rounded corners}{},
    where level={2}{rounded corners}{},
    where level={3}{diamond,minimum width=3cm}{},
    edge+={rounded corners=5pt, -{Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt},
  },
[{$ax+by+c=0$}\\
{$a'x+b'y+c'=0$},
  [{$\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a'}{b'}$}
    [{$\displaystyle\frac{b}{b'}=\frac{c}{c'}$}
      [coincide,tier=word]
    ]
    [{$\displaystyle\frac{b}{b'}\ne\frac{c}{c'}$},
    edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) --+(5mm,0)
    |-(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}
     [parallel,tier=word]]
    ]
  [{$\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}\ne\frac{a'}{b'}$},
    edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) --+(5mm,0)
    |-(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}
    [{intersect at\\ one point},tier=word,diamond,minimum width=3cm,rounded
    corners=0pt]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I see it is the 'forest', with tree that grows east. Perhaps I can use this sample to produce many applications. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. It's my first question here. Does it work? I clicked the checkmark.