# Drawing a centered and connected hierarchical diagram

Tags: diagrams, forest

This question builds upon a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573415/drawing-a-more-connected-hierarchical-diagram) I posted here.

The following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, calc, shadows}

\colorlet{mygreen}{green!75!black}
\colorlet{col1in}{red!30}
\colorlet{col1out}{red!40}
\colorlet{col2in}{mygreen!40}
\colorlet{col2out}{mygreen!50}
\colorlet{col3in}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col3out}{blue!40}
\colorlet{col4in}{mygreen!20}
\colorlet{col4out}{mygreen!30}
\colorlet{col5in}{blue!10}
\colorlet{col5out}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6in}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6out}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col7out}{orange}
\colorlet{col7in}{orange!50}
\colorlet{col8out}{orange!40}
\colorlet{col8in}{orange!20}
\colorlet{linecol}{blue!60}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/forest,
  rect/.append style   = {rectangle, rounded corners = 2pt,
                         inner color = col6in, outer color = col6out},
  ellip/.append style  = {ellipse, inner color = col5in,
                          outer color = col5out},
  orect/.append style  = {rect, font = \sffamily\bfseries\LARGE,
                         text width = 325pt, text centered,
                         minimum height = 10pt, outer color = col7out,
                         inner color=col7in},
  oellip/.append style = {ellip, inner color = col8in, outer color = col8out,
                          font = \sffamily\bfseries\large, text centered}}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
      font=\sffamily\bfseries,
      line width=1pt,
      draw=linecol,
      ellip,
      align=center,
      child anchor=north,
      parent anchor=south,
      drop shadow,
      l sep'+=12.5pt,
      edge+={color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt, >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->},
      edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)},
  }
  [Start, inner color=col1in, outer color=col1out,name=rootNode
    [X1, inner color=col2in, outer color=col2out, name=X1
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y1
            [Short, rect, name=Z1
            ]
            [Short, rect, name=Z2
            ]
            [Short, rect, name=Z3
            ]
            [Short, rect, name=Z4
            ]
            [Short, rect, name=Z5
            ]
            [Short, rect, name=Z6
            ]
            [Short, rect, name=Z7
            ]
            [Short, rect, name=Z8
            ]
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y2
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y3
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y4
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y5
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y6
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y7
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y8
          ]
    ]
    [X2, inner color=col3in, outer color=col3out,name=X2
    ]
  ]
  \begin{scope}[color = linecol, rounded corners = 5pt, >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->]
    \draw (X2.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Y1.child anchor);
    \draw (Y1.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z1.child anchor);
    \draw (Y2.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z2.child anchor);
    \draw (Y3.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z3.child anchor);
    \draw (Y4.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z4.child anchor);
    \draw (Y5.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,-5pt) -| (Z1.child anchor);
    \draw (Y6.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z1.child anchor);
    \draw (Y7.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z1.child anchor);
    \draw (Y8.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z1.child anchor);
  \end{scope}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image: Output image].

However, this is very left-centered. I would like to have a centered output, such that every row of the output diagram aligns with the parent row. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: did you want something like the answer below

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, calc, shadows}

\colorlet{mygreen}{green!75!black}
\colorlet{col1in}{red!30}
\colorlet{col1out}{red!40}
\colorlet{col2in}{mygreen!40}
\colorlet{col2out}{mygreen!50}
\colorlet{col3in}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col3out}{blue!40}
\colorlet{col4in}{mygreen!20}
\colorlet{col4out}{mygreen!30}
\colorlet{col5in}{blue!10}
\colorlet{col5out}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6in}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6out}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col7out}{orange}
\colorlet{col7in}{orange!50}
\colorlet{col8out}{orange!40}
\colorlet{col8in}{orange!20}
\colorlet{linecol}{blue!60}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/forest,
  rect/.append style   = {rectangle, rounded corners = 2pt,
                         inner color = col6in, outer color = col6out},
  ellip/.append style  = {ellipse, inner color = col5in,
                          outer color = col5out},
  orect/.append style  = {rect, font = \sffamily\bfseries\LARGE,
                         text width = 325pt, text centered,
                         minimum height = 10pt, outer color = col7out,
                         inner color=col7in},
  oellip/.append style = {ellip, inner color = col8in, outer color = col8out,
                          font = \sffamily\bfseries\large, text centered}}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
      font=\sffamily\bfseries,
      line width=1pt,
      draw=linecol,
      ellip,
      align=center,
      child anchor=north,
      parent anchor=south,
      drop shadow,
      l sep'+=12.5pt,
      edge+={color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt, >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->},
      edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)},
  }
  [Start, inner color=col1in, outer color=col1out,name=rootNode
    [X1, inner color=col2in, outer color=col2out, name=X1
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y1
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y2
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y3
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y4
          [Short, rect, name=Z1
          ]
          [Short, rect, name=Z2
          ]
          [Short, rect, name=Z3
          ]
          [Short, rect, name=Z4
          ]
          [Short, rect, name=Z5
          ]
          [Short, rect, name=Z6
          ]
          [Short, rect, name=Z7
          ]
          [Short, rect, name=Z8
          ]]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y5
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y6
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y7
          ]
          [A longer string, rect, name=Y8
          ]
    ]
    [X2, inner color=col3in, outer color=col3out,name=X2
    ]
  ]
  \begin{scope}[color = linecol, rounded corners = 5pt, >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->]
    \draw (X2.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Y1.child anchor);
    \draw (Y1.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z1.child anchor);
    \draw (Y2.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z2.child anchor);
    \draw (Y3.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z3.child anchor);
    \draw (Y4.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z4.child anchor);
    \draw (Y5.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,-5pt) -| (Z1.child anchor);
    \draw (Y6.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z1.child anchor);
    \draw (Y7.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z1.child anchor);
    \draw (Y8.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (Z1.child anchor);
  \end{scope}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```